# How can I populate a TreeViw with a List<object> and display properties without duplicates?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I have an `Entry` class, with properties `Building`, `Floor`, `Room`, and `Product`. I receive a spreadsheet that gets turned into a `List<Entry>`, and here's a small example of what it looks like:

```
List<Entry> Entries.Add(new Entry("Building A", "Floor 4", "Room 6", "Printer"));
List<Entry> Entries.Add(new Entry("Building A", "Floor 4", "Room 6", "Computer Monitor"));
List<Entry> Entries.Add(new Entry("Building A", "Floor 5", "Room 8", "Office Desk"));
List<Entry> Entries.Add(new Entry("Building B", "Floor 2", "Room 8", "Printer"));
List<Entry> Entries.Add(new Entry("Building B", "Floor 2", "Room 12", "Office Chair"));
```

I would like to display this list of objects in a `TreeView` like so:

```
Building A
--Floor 4
----Room 6
------Printer
------Computer Monitor
--Floor 5
----Room 8
------Office Desk
Building B
--Floor 2
----Room 8
------Printer
----Room 12
------Office Chair
```

Notice how there are no duplicates in the TreeView: How Floor 4 Room 6 **didn't appear twice** even though it appeared two times in the `List<Entry> Entries` list. This is what I am trying to accomplish. I am not concerned with duplicates in my `Entries` list, as I will be using the `TreeView` to reference `Entry` later.

I've tried using a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` in many different ways and haven't had any luck. I've tried making `Building`, `Floor`, `Room`, and `Product` nested classes in `Entry` with no luck, and all the examples I see of `HierarchicalDataTemplate` use a class that contains another `List<object>` as a parameter, which is not what I have.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some collections in .NET that disallow duplicates. HashSet is one such collection, and I think SortedSet also prevents dupes (with the added overhead of sorting). There may be others. So, you could use such a collection to remove the dupes.

However, that may not work as expected if you do not also add equality members to your class or struct. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type

You could always write a function to remove the dupes, but you'll have to address "What constitutes a dupe?" - and that is the same question you'll be answering by creating the equality members (Equals and GetHashCode).

Comment: Thanks! Let me look into this solution. I originally replied that I have already looked into this but I think my SortedSet equality members were not set up the way I needed.